# curl error 55 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/magento/language-pt_br~dev.json

Tags: curl, magento, centos, github-actions

I have a github actions workflow for deployment of magento application, while trying to deploy any change, the first run throws the below error, and when we re-run the failed job, it runs successfully, it has been happening for about 6 months now.

**Below is the error log from github pipeline**

`https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 55 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/magento/language-pt_br~dev.json: Failed sending data to the peer), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`

This job runs-on centos 7 with

````
curl 7.61.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1c zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.6 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh/0.9.0/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.41.0
Release-Date: 2018-09-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz brotli TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL Metalink```
````

Comment: You are using a very old curl version. Could you test it with the latest curl 8.2.0 ? 
For me it is still happening with the latest version but a PUT request it seems to be fixed in curl itself. I am still looking for a way to reproduce it properly...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i also tested with latest curl version, facing same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error. It occures when you have the minimum stability in composer.json set at "dev" clear cache and switch over to "stable" and everything should work

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, let me try your suggestion, will get back after the try

Comment: unfortunately this solution is also not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Brandon, infact this is working 100%, previously i was making changes on persistanct memory files, where the changes were not reflecting inside the container and when i try to do it directly inside the container and run composer install, it works.

Comment: but what if i want minimum stability in "dev" ?